# Perform different VLOOKUPs based on value of =RIGHT value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula, vlookup

**Summary:**

I am needing to `=VLOOKUP` different column numbers based on the outcome of a `=RIGHT` statement. My current formula performs this as expected, but isn't easily scalable should I need to add more potential outcomes of the `=RIGHT` statement. Is there any way to scale this effectively?

**Use Case:**

I have a formula that inserts either `"Use 1"`, `"Use 2"`, `"Use 3"`, `"Use 4"` or `"Unknown"`, into Column `A`. Column `B` then need to perform a `=VLOOKUP`, which will vary depending on what the last character is in column `A` and return a different column number. For example, if cell `A1` contains the text `"Use 1"`, I will need to return the 2nd column in the `=VLOOKUP`. If cell `A2` contains `"Use 4"`, I will need to return the 8th column in the `=VLOOKUP` **(the column number is non-linear)**.

**Current Code:**

`=IFS(RIGHT(A2,1)="1",VLOOKUP(B2,'Table2'!A:I,2,FALSE),RIGHT(A2,1)="2",VLOOKUP(B2,'Table2'!A:I,4,FALSE),RIGHT(A2,1)="3",VLOOKUP(B2,'Table2'!A:I,5,FALSE),RIGHT(A2,1)="4",VLOOKUP(B2,'Table2'!A:I,8,FALSE),RIGHT(A2,1)="N","NotFound")`

**Example Table using above code:**

- Code Table

| Check | ThingToFind | Code Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Use 1 | FOO | ABC |
| Use 3 | BAR | 012 |
| Use 4 | BAZ | IN |
| Unknown |  |  |

- Table2

| ThingToFind | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 | Data4 | Data5 | Data6 | Data7 | Data8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FOO | ABC | DEF | GHI | JKL | MNO | PQR | STU | VWX |
| BAR | 123 | 456 | 789 | 012 | 345 | 678 | 901 | 234 |
| BAZ | SOME | THING | TO | LOOK | UP | GOES | IN | HERE |

**Conclusion:**

The above example works fine for the previous use case, but I am trying to make this scalable without needing to edit the formula every time the `Check` column may get new additions (such as `"Use 5"` or `"Use 12"`. Is there any way of doing this practically? My thought was to use a separate table to `=VLOOKUP` the column number (so I would only need to edit this table and not the formulas each time), but it appears I am unable to use a different `=VLOOKUP` for the `COL_INDEX_NUM` portion of the initial `=VLOOKUP`. Any help with this would be appreciated. I am using MSO 365.

Comment: Use a look-up table with the "Check column" as row and column number as column?

Comment: Unless you're meaning something different, this is what I tried in my conclusion. It appears that it doesn't allow me to use a lookup table to `=VLOOKUP` against as a column number. For example, I put all of the values from the `=RIGHT` formula in column `A` of a new table, and all of the correct column numbers in column `B` of the new table. I tried to `=VLOOKUP` column `B` for the `COL_INDEX_NUM` section of the initial `=VLOOKUP`, but it doesn't allow it (unless I'm doing something wrong). Here's what I tried, with the outcome: https://i.imgur.com/3NbwDnv.png. Thanks! :)

Comment: You're looking up the wrong thing in that formula (right(a2,1)), but since you have two solutions probably not worth pursuing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options seem to be completely arbitrairy, and since the options under 'use' seem lineair to those, I'd suggest to use `CHOOSE()`:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,E$2:M$4,CHOOSE(--MID(A2,5,99),2,4,5,8),0),"")
```

Dragged down...

---

The logic here is:

- `--MID(A2,5,99)` - Used to grab the number from the A-column. These seem to be lineair (or will result in an error if 'Unknown').
- The result of the above is input for the 1st parameter of `CHOOSE()`, and since they are lineair we can then write each value in the 2nd up to 5th parameter. Scale this if needed.
- The `VLOOKUP()` works as expected and should now return the columns as per outcome above.
- `IFERROR()` is there to catch any error given by 'Unknown'.

---

Since `BYROW()` appears to be in production, it won't harm to add the alternative to create a single formula for a spilling array. This would mean you only ever need to adjust a single formula:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=BYROW(A2:B5,LAMBDA(X,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(X,2),E$2:M$4,CHOOSE(--MID(INDEX(X,1),5,99),2,4,5,8),0),"")))
```

---

Btw, kudos for well written questions!

Comment: 3 days running - thank you once again! Really appreciate the expanded logic, too. It makes sense to focus on the part of the data that is linear, instead of the part that isn't. Thanks so much for your help with this. The initial formula works perfectly, but the others are good to know, too!

Answer (score 3):

Kind of dirty but works perfect:

[image]

Aboe your Table2, add a transposed row with those Use 1, Use 2 ...Use N in the position where you want the value to be extracted. Then combine VLOOKUP with MATCH.

My formula in column D is:

```
=VLOOKUP(B3;$A$14:$I$16;MATCH(A3;$A$12:$I$12;0);FALSE)
```

You cam trap this into an IF.ERROR or IF for the `Unknown` option.

The advantage of this approach is that you can add/switch more `Use N`easily just changing the target ranges.

Comment: Thank you! It works as intended, even if a little messy. As JvdV's solution was provided first and was correct, I have awarded him the Solution here, but provided an updoot for the time. I may have use for this similar setup in the future, so it's much appreciated!